# Can you help me to find the error below in the ResultSet rs=stmt....?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting a error on the resultset rs part where netbeans shows the error as

> incompatible types:int cannot be converted to resultset

```
Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?useSSL=false", "root", "abc");

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String query = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE Mobile_No='" + mobno + "';"; /*Get the value from the database*/
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeUpdate(query);/*Part where the error is appearing*/

while (rs.next()) {
    String Name = rs.getString("Name");
    String Age = rs.getString("Age");
    String Mobile = rs.getString("Mobile_No");
    String gender = rs.getString("Gender");
    String symptoms = rs.getString("Symptoms");
    model.addRow(new Object[]{Name, Age, Mobile, gender, symptoms});
}

rs.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `stmt.executeQuery(String sql)`, it returns `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a ResultSet returned you should use executeQuery, not executeUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

The `stmt.executeUpdate(query);` doesn't fit for an `SELECT` query.

You need to replace it by `stmt.executeQuery(query);`

Answer (score 0):

Well the method `executeUpdate` returns a int not a results set, seen in the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)
the integer being return being either `(1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing`

the method you are actually want to use is `executeQuery` and the documentation for that can be found at:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

According the Javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-), `stmt.executeUpdate(query);` returns an `int` and not a `ResultSet` object.

From the Javadoc :

> **Returns:**
>   either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

I think you must use `stmt.executeQuery(query);` instead, which return the `ResultSet` you expect. You're doing a `SELECT` and not an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` operation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe people have already answered your question, which is `statement.executeUpdate(query)` returns the number of how many rows has been affected by executing the `query`, and you should use `statement.executeQuery(query)` instead ..

But this part `String query = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE Mobile_No = '" + mobno + "';"` is very bad approach, it will leave the door opened for `SQL injection`, you should use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement`